# foreach inside the for loop; keep looping

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I'm practicing on foreach and for loop at the moment and combining them leads me to unexpected result. Below is a foreach statement inside the for loop statement.

> PHP:

```
<?php
$names = array("A", "B", "C", "D"); 

for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) 
{
    foreach ($names as $name) 
    {
        echo "$name = $i ";
    }
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

`A = 0 B = 0 C = 0 D = 0 A = 1 B = 1 C = 1 D = 1 A = 2 B = 2 C = 2 D = 2 A = 3 B = 3 C = 3 D = 3`

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

`A = 0 B = 1 C= 2 D = 3`

Kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong and what is the solution for this.

PS: I don't want to used array keys and values. :)

Comment: *PS: I don't want to used array key* <- In this there is your answer

Comment: you're running nested loops, for every iteration of your `for` loop, the `foreach` loop will iterate the ENTIRE `$names` array. so you have 4 external iterations, 3 internal iterations, leave you with 4x3 = 12 `echo` calls.

Comment: @MarcB how can I do only 1 iteration?

Comment: remove the `for` loop. if all you want to do is print out the $names array, then you just need the `foreach`. basically you have a grocery list that says "buy bread, milk, eggs", then your significant other sends you to the store 4 times. so you buy break/milk/eggs 4 times, and end up wondering why you have 4 loaves, 4 jugs of milk, and 4 egg cartons.

Comment: I'd remove the outer loop and put the $i counter inside the FOREACH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `foreach` only:

```
foreach($names as $key => $value) {
   echo "$value: $key";
}
```

You don't need to nest loop styles just to get the array keys - PHP can trivially give them to you with the `as $key => $value` version of foreach.

Comment: See the PS in OP's question: *PS: I don't want to used array keys and values. :)* Don't ask my why not.

Comment: then what you want is impossible. "I have an array with keys and values. I don't want keys and values". Then you can't have an array.

Comment: I know it's already late for Canadians :) But: *you want* I don't want it, OP wrote that.

Comment: oops, right... I've had my head stuck in drop ceilings all day pulling cables. I'm blind from all the tile dust.

Comment: Anyway, I think that is the best solution for OP, and I can't understand why OP don't want to use the keys.

Comment: some reason I don't want to use the keys

Comment: well, what if the array modified, or a key was deleted? YOu can't assume they'll always be sequential. e.g. `$foo = array(); $foo[1] = 'bar'; $foo[999999] = 'baz';`. oops, now the $i++ versions won't work, because you'll be spitting out 1/2 when it should be 1/999999

Answer (score 2):

foreach loops through the entire array every pass through the outer loop. Try this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo "$name = $i ";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use While loop

```
$names = array("A", "B", "C", "D"); 
$i=0;

    foreach ($names as $name) 
    {
        echo "$name = $i ";
        $i++;
        array_pop($names);
    }
```

**result:**

> A = 0 B = 1 C = 2 D = 3

Comment: So what's the point of having a while, if it'll only run once?

Comment: @MarcB I guess just for the fun of it.